# switchMap calling function twice

Tags: angular, typescript

The function in switchMap is calling twice. I don't understand why but it is happening. Could you help me with that problem? I need to call this function once.

```
search(status = 0, groupId = 0, purchaseId = 0, pagedSearchQueries: Observable<PagedSearchQuery>): Observable<PurchaseItemListResult> {
    return pagedSearchQueries.pipe(
      debounce(val => val.isAutoLoad ? timer(1) : timer(400)),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(pagedSearchQuery => this.searchItems(status, groupId, purchaseId, pagedSearchQuery))
    );
  }

  private searchItems(status = 0, groupId = 0, purchaseId = 0, pagedSearchQuery: PagedSearchQuery): Observable<PurchaseItemListResult> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('status', status.toString())
      .set('groupId', groupId.toString())
      .set('purchaseId', purchaseId.toString())
      .set('offset', pagedSearchQuery.offset.toString())
      .set('limit', pagedSearchQuery.limit.toString());

    return this.http
      .get<PurchaseItemListItem[]>(`${this.endpoint}?search=${pagedSearchQuery.query}`, {
        observe: 'response',
        params
      }).pipe(
        map(res => {
          return new PurchaseItemListResult(parseInt(res.headers.get('X-Total-Count'), 10),
          pagedSearchQuery.offset,
          pagedSearchQuery.limit,
          pagedSearchQuery.query,
          res.body);
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Comment: Probably because the pagedSearchQueries observable emits two events...

Comment: Or two subscribers, perhaps?

Comment: the search function is being called by a function that has a subscriber. I don't know 2 subscribers. I am very new on Angular.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because of multiple subscriptions, like @mbojko is saying. Can you post the "function that has a subscriber"?

Try to add the `share` operator after `switchMap`. This multicasts the current observable to multiple subscriptions and will be active if there is at least one subscription. Everything before `share` will just be executed once.

```js
search(status = 0, groupId = 0, purchaseId = 0, pagedSearchQueries: Observable<PagedSearchQuery>): Observable<PurchaseItemListResult> {
  return pagedSearchQueries.pipe(
    debounce(val => val.isAutoLoad ? timer(1) : timer(400)),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(pagedSearchQuery => this.searchItems(status, groupId, purchaseId, pagedSearchQuery)),
    share()
  );
}
```

Subscriptions in Angular can be made if you either use the observables `.subscribe()` or if you use the `async` pipe in a template. Each of them will produce a new subscription.

Comment: Had multiple `async` in multiple places. This clarification helped fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the feedback.